# Subsection is unevenly alligned

Tags: formatting

I'm working on an outline for my general psych class, but I came across this error.  I'm new at LaTeX so I'm not sure how to go about fixing it.  Thank you so much for your help!  [image]  [image]

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, you have it within the itemize environment. This would cause the indentation.

Comment: Perfect.  Thank you so much!  I've been working on this for awhile and I didn't know that factored into the design!  Best wishes!

Comment: You're very welcome :) to avoid this problem, it helps to use an editor that can collapse environments. TeXmaker comes to mind or, if you're a real pro, Emacs with AUCTeX.

Comment: @SeanAllred I will definitely check those out!  I've just been using an online editor, but it's not working out that great :P

Comment: Although the solution is found, it is a good a idea, to post code by copy and paste directly into the TeX.SE editor instead of a screen shot of the editor window. You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Will do!